# How to close jquery datepicker

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a datepicker similar to this one [datepicker](http://jsfiddle.net/sWbfk/). In this case, The datepicker is tied to a div and not to an input but the date outout is displayed in the input field. But the datepicker does not close when date is selected. I tried to showbuttonpanel but upon clicking the button it does not close as well. Hidind is not option here because when I tried and open again, it does not open any more.
Problem is how to close the datepicke especially after selecting a date?

```
<p>
    Dates:
    <label><b>To:</b></label>
    <input type="text" id="input1" size="10">
    <label><b>From:</b></label>
    <input type="text" id="input2" size="10">
</p>
<div class="datepicker"></div>
```

Comment: is there a reason why you decide to use div instead of input? jquery ui datepicker uses the input behavior to work properly so use input instead of div

Comment: I used div so that in window resize the calendar sticks with the input field. If i use input, the calendar does not stick with input on window resize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$(this).datepicker("destroy")` to remove the datepicker once the user has filled in both inputs.

You can only use `hide` if the datepicker opens on demand, not for one that's displayed permanently in a DIV.

```
$(".datepicker").datepicker({
  minDate: 0,
  numberOfMonths: [3, 1],
  beforeShowDay: function(date) {
    var date1 = $.datepicker.parseDate($.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, $("#input1").val());
    var date2 = $.datepicker.parseDate($.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, $("#input2").val());
    return [true, date1 && ((date.getTime() == date1.getTime()) || (date2 && date >= date1 && date <= date2)) ? "dp-highlight" : ""];
  },
  onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
    var date1 = $.datepicker.parseDate($.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, $("#input1").val());
    var date2 = $.datepicker.parseDate($.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, $("#input2").val());
    var selectedDate = $.datepicker.parseDate($.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, dateText);


    if (!date1 || date2) {
      $("#input1").val(dateText);
      $("#input2").val("");
      $(this).datepicker();
    } else if (selectedDate < date1) {
      $("#input2").val($("#input1").val());
      $("#input1").val(dateText);
      $(this).datepicker();
    } else {
      $("#input2").val(dateText);
      $(this).datepicker();
    }
    if ($("#input1").val() && $("#input2").val()) {
        $(this).datepicker("destroy");
    }
  }
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/sWbfk/567/)

Answer (score 0):

I already created a demo on [CodePen](https://codepen.io/marcobiedermann/pen/mwaKxL). Maybe this might help you out.

```
<form action="https://httpbin.org/post" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="date" class="js-ui-datepicker">
</form>


$('.js-ui-datepicker').one('focus', function() {
  $(this)
    .datepicker({
      minDate: 0,
      showButtonPanel: true,
    })
    .datepicker('show');
  $('#ui-datepicker-div').draggable();
});
```